# iOS - UILabels and Gestures

Tags: ios, uilabel, uigesturerecognizer

I have UILabels that get animated which move left and right on the screen, and I want to be able to drag them even while they are being animated. Anyone have any idea how to do that?

```
WordLabel *firstWordLabel = [[WordLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 100, 10, 35) andWithWord:firstWord];

firstWordLabel.text = firstWord.word;
[firstWordLabel sizeToFit];
firstWordLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self
                                    action:@selector(labelDragged:)];
[firstWordLabel addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

[self.view addSubview:firstWordLabel];

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

CGRect newRect = firstWordLabel.frame;
newRect.origin.x = floor(screenWidth/2);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
firstWordLabel.frame = newRect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: You should have a look into POP (https://github.com/facebook/pop) from facebook. As far as I know, this was the main reason, they created the framework.

Comment: Does it allow you to add a gesture to it?

Comment: I don't know. But it's open source. So you can look yourself.

Comment: Any tips on how to install it? I'm having trouble including it into my project. It won't let me import it using the <>

Comment: @Mikerizzo i updated the code check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't u know use of `beginAnimations`, `commitAnimations` are discouraged after iOS 4 and later see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) so use block based animation methods instead for example

u can use like below 
try this hope this might helps

```
    //first create a view which holds the label for example
     UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 100, 10, 35)];



    WordLabel *firstWordLabel = [[WordLabel alloc] initWithFrame:holderView.bounds andWithWord:firstWord];

    firstWordLabel.text = firstWord.word;
    [firstWordLabel sizeToFit];
    firstWordLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                initWithTarget:self
                                action:@selector(labelDragged:)];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    [holderView addSubview:firstWordLabel]; 
    [self.view addSubview:holderView];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    CGRect newRect = firstWordLabel.frame;
    newRect.origin.x = floor(screenWidth/2);

    //add the block based animation with option UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
   holderView.frame = newRect;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       NSLog(@"completed");
    }];
```

for what i did like below try it in new project for testing

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
      UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 50, 35)];

      firstWordLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:holderView.bounds]; //is a member variable

      firstWordLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
      firstWordLabel.text = @"Hello";

       UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(labelDragged:)];
       [holderView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
       firstWordLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
       [holderView addSubview:firstWordLabel];
       [self.view addSubview:holderView];

   }

 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self startTheAnimation]; //calling animation
  }

  - (void)startTheAnimation
 {
     CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
     CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

     CGRect newRect = firstWordLabel.frame;
     newRect.origin.x = floor(screenWidth/2);

     [UIView animateWithDuration:20.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
     firstWordLabel.frame = newRect;


     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
       NSLog(@"completed");
     }];

  }

  - (void)labelDragged:(id)sender
  {
    NSLog(@"Dragged");
   }
```

Comment: Still doesn't catch the gesture on the label. Not sure why not.

Comment: still no dice. I changed the colour of the holder view to see what it looks like and it doesn't contain the moving label.

Comment: just add the uilabel and try

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52396/discussion-between-mikerizzo-and-shan)

Comment: what does your labelDragged method do?